# Ubuntu 12.04 installed but won't boot, no other OS

Tags: 12.04, boot-failure, installation

OS  Ubuntu 12.04 installed from USB
Computer   Toshiba Satellite
Old OS:  Vista

Hello,

I installed ubuntu 12.04 from a usb.  during the installation I installed Ubuntu over windows so all windows was deleted.  After installation was complete it asked for a re-boot and I re-booted.  It went to a screen with a flashing cursor in the top right corner.  I then re-booted the comp. from usb and it takes me to a page that has at the top  GNU GRUB version 1.99-2ubuntu3.1

further below I have options to choose.

```
ubuntu with linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae
ubuntu with linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae (recovery mode)
memtest86+
memtest86+ serial console 115200
```

after i choose the first two optionsit goes back to the following screen

```
mountall: error while loading shared libraries;/lib/libply.so.2: invalid ELF
```

I am not sure what to do here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is fix to this problem given on [this](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/securitymonkey/ubuntu-psa-fixing-mountall-failure-at-boot-on-ubuntu-lucid-alpha-37440) site.You will need wired internet and a bootable device to fix it though.